# Are the results of the Linux time command affected by system load?

Tags: linux, time, load, benchmarking

I'm using the Linux shell `time` and GNU time commands for some basic benchmarking.

But my system occasionally has varying load from other users.

Are the "user" and "sys" outputs affected by these other users?

I would think for a program with pure processing, that the results should be unaffected as the OS is (I would think) capable of tracking process time shares pretty exactly.

I'm less sure what the outputs would be for I/O heavy processes.

Can anyone explain these relations? Citations are always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The time command does not report context switching overhead since it is not a system call. So you won't see any change in system time output due to context switches. If there is resource contention due to IO/CPU requests from other users, then this will impact your blocking time and completion time hence the `sys` and `user` times can go really high.